# Django Migrations Problems

Tags: django, migration

I am facing a migration issue in Django related to a model inheritance and field modification. Initially, I had a `TaggedModel` with a `tags` field, and a `Book` model inheriting from it with another `tags` field. I created a lot of instances of the Book model then I Realized the redundancy, then I decided to remove the `tags` field from the `Book` model and retain only the one from the `TaggedModel`.

After making this change, I expected Django to generate a `RemoveField` migration, but instead, it generated an `AlterField` migration. Here's the relevant code:

```
class TaggedModel(models.Model):
    tags = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=TAG_MAX_LENGTH, blank=True),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Book(TaggedModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey("BookCategory", on_delete=CASCADE)
    tags = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True),
        blank=True,
    )
    # Removed tags field from here
```

And the migration file:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.fields
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('test', '0084_remove_inputs'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='book',
            name='tags',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(
                base_field=models.CharField(
                    blank=True, 
                    max_length=100
                ), 
                blank=True, 
                null=True, 
                size=None
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

I'm trying to understand why Django generated an AlterField migration instead of a RemoveField migration. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did the `Book` model look like before the change?

Answer (score 0):

@michjnich thank you for your message
Before:

```
class Book(TaggedModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey("BookCategory", on_delete=CASCADE)
    tags = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True),
        blank=True,
    )
```

After

```
class Book(TaggedModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey("BookCategory", on_delete=CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I find the reason for that,
Before the code change, the tags field used belonged to the Book model defined as follows:

```
tags = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True),
        blank=True,
    )
```

Following the deletion of the "tags" field, the model now uses the one defined in the TaggedModel class:

```
class TaggedModel(models.Model):
    tags = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=TAG_MAX_LENGTH, blank=True),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The main difference between the "tags" field in the Book class and that in the TaggedModel class is that, in the TaggedModel class, the "tags" field can be null (null=True), whereas previously, the "tags" field " in class Book couldn't be zero. This is why, after the migration, the properties of the "tags" field have changed, which explains the use of the AlterField instruction.

What do you think ?